# WPF ListBoxEdit control - Raise PageDown event programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, keyevent

I ve got a ListBoxEdit DevExpress control in WPF and I want to page down / page up its contents when clicking another button.

In the UI, when I focus on the ListBoxEdit control and key PageDown it works.

When I try programmatically it fails. My code is below where DataSourceList is the x:Name of my ListBoxEdit control.

```
var presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromDependencyObject(this.DataSourceList);
var args = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, presentationSource, 0, Key.PageDown);

args.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
this.DataSourceList.RaiseEvent(args);
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :)

```
var child = this.DataSourceList.VisualChildren().FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetType() == typeof(ListBoxEditItem));
if (child != null)
{
       var args = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0,Key.PageDown);
       args.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
       args.Source = child;
       InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(args);
}
```

It seems that `this.DataSourceList.RaiseEvent(args);` didn't do the the trick, while the Source of the event has to be the ListBoxEditItem rather than the ListBoxEdit control.